# How To Remove "Insert Metropcs Sim Card. Emergency Calls Only" Msg On An Lg?

Tags: sim-card, lg

This is the message I am looking to get rid of:

[image]

I learned that you can get rid of this message on other Androids by going to the app that it generated from and clicking "disable notifications". However, I have no idea where to find the app that causes this message and I also can't long-press the message to see where it comes from. So any other answers to solve this problem? Or do any of you guys know what app cause these sorts of messages to pop up on your homescreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your phone is SIMLocked, meaning it works only with SIMCards from a certain service provider, **MetroPCS** in this specific case. Your phone doesn't detect any MetroPCS SIMCards inserted. Therefore, it limits your calls to *emergency only*. That notification doesn't originate from any app. It originates from the OS itself. Only way to make it go away is, assuming you wouldn't root your device, installing a proper SIMCard.